# repetitive global variable and try except in python unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

I have started using Python Selenium and wrote a script shown below.

This prints a return code linked to the test that fails (test01, test02, test03, ..).

Ignore that each test is checking the same thing.

I'm just trying to understand if there's a cleaner way to write the tests because each one repetitively declares `global res`, and then has a `try/except` block.

Could anyone offer some advice on how to improve this please?

```
# global variable for return code. Zero is success.
res=0

@atexit.register
def send_health():
    print ("res=%s") % res

class Login(unittest2.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(inst):
        binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
        inst.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
        inst.base_url = "https://stackoverflow.com"

    def test01(self):
        global res
        driver = self.driver
        try:
            self.assertEqual("Ask a Question", driver.title)
        except Exception,e:
            print ("Exception: %s" % e)
            driver.save_screenshot('screenshot_test01.png')
            res=1
            return

    def test02(self):
        global res
        driver = self.driver
        try:
            self.assertEqual("Ask a Question", driver.title)
        except Exception,e:
            print ("Exception: %s" % e)
            driver.save_screenshot('screenshot_test02.png')
            res=2
            return

    def test03(self):
        global res
        driver = self.driver
        try:
            self.assertEqual("Ask a Question", driver.title)
        except Exception,e:
            print ("Exception: %s" % e)
            driver.save_screenshot('screenshot_test03.png')
            res=3
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest2.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips above. I've reduced the code down to this version which hopefully looks cleaner and more standard:

```
class Login(unittest2.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def handleError(self, e, res):
        print ("Test failed with exception: %s" % e)
        self.result = res
        sys.exit()

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
        self.base_url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
        self.result = 0

    def test01(self):
        driver = self.driver
        try:
            self.assertEqual("Ask a Question", driver.title)
        except Exception,e:
            self.handleError(e, 1)

    def test02(self):
        driver = self.driver
        try:
            self.assertEqual("Ask a Question", driver.title)
        except Exception,e:
            self.handleError(e, 2)

    def test03(self):
        driver = self.driver
        try:
            self.assertEqual("Ask a Question", driver.title)
        except Exception,e:
            self.handleError(e, 3)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        print ("res=%s") % self.result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest2.main()
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for global variables here at all. You are inside a class; use `self.res` throughout.

Comment: Thanks Daniel I will try this out.

Comment: That breaks when it calls the `send_health` exit function

    `print ("res=%s") % self.res`
    `NameError: global name 'self' is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what `setUp` instance method is for, quite similar to `setUpClass` method that is run once per test class.

```
def setUp(self):
    # this code will be executed before each and every test
    self.res = 0

def tearDown(self):
    # this code will be executed post each and every test.
```

By the way, why are you using global variables? There's no need for them. In fact, there's seldom a valid rationale for using globals. Moreover, tests need to be isolated and independent, using global variables would violate that rule.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am using `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` because the test requires logging into the site and then clicking through a journey.

Comment: @Edward I have no issue with using the `setUpClass`. However, you don't need a global res value. Tests need to be isolated, so sharing a value between them is not at all advisable.